# Do finite subgroups of $G/H$ correspond to finite subgroups of $G$ containing $H$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a normal *finite* subgroup of $G$.

It is known that subgroups of the quotient group $G/H$ correspond to subgroups of $G$ containing $H$.

Does the statement still hold replacing "subgroups" by "finite subgroups"?

Clearly, every finite subgroup $F$ in $G$ is sent to a finite subgroup of $G/H$ via the projection $\pi: G \to G/H$. Does every finite subgroup of $G/H$ arise this way?

Comment: If you know that every subgroup of $G/H$ is of the form $K/H$ where $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, then what can you say about the order of such a subgroup if $K$ is infinite?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think I got it: the (finite) order of $K/H$ is the index $|K:H|$. Now if $K$ is infinite, then the index $|K:H|$ must also be infinite since $H$ is finite, contradiction!

Comment: Exactly! Nice work :). You can post a quick answer with this in if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K/H$ be a finite subgroup of $G/H$ (with $K$ a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$). Then the (finite) order of $K/H$ is the index $|K:H|$.

Then $K$ is finite, otherwise $|K:H|$ must be infinite since $H$ is finite, yielding a contradiction.